# Why does Colaboratory Google take much longer than Pycharm?

Tags: python, time, pycharm, google-colaboratory, delay

Are there any factors in the python code that could justify the delay in generating the results? I plotted a gif of orbits in Pycharm and the result took about 5 seconds. On Google Collaboration it took 3 minutes. Can I do anything to improve this?

Comment: When you execute a Python script from Pycharm, it's run on your local hardware, usually with memory and cores to spare.  On the other hand, when you execute a script in Colab, it's executed on a remote server, competing for machine resources with possibly hundreds (?) of other user scripts. It's not particularly surprising that you get the fastest execution when the script runs on your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

On the top left, click Runtime >> Change runtime type.

Where it says None in Hardware accelerator, change it to GPU.

That's if you are doing Machine Learning.

Comment: I change it, but its still taking a long time to plot

Answer (score -1):

I think you should set *Hardware accelerator* to GPU in *Notebook Settings*.

Comment: I change it, but its still taking a long time to plot